# sql query work only with small strings and not with big length strings

Tags: php, mysql

here's the php script tht gets the string and insert it in the db .

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$message = nl2br($message); 
if(isset($name) && isset($message)){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO messages VALUES('','".$name."', '".$message."')";
    if($sqlrun = mysqli_query($connection , $sql)){
        header('Location:../write.php');
    }else{
        echo "query doesnt work";
    }
}

?>
```

what can be the reason it works only with small strings?
in the database the field is a text that contain 1000 bits maximum .

Comment: Are 1000 bits or 1000 bytes?

Comment: What is the actual type of the field? A VARCHAR(1000)? Is the text you are inserting UNICODE or ASCII?

Comment: FYI your query is very vulnerable. Check [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Can you provide structure of the database? I think you should use `TEXT` type for the field `message`

Comment: Unrelated: always call `exit;` after sending a location header, unless you want the rest of your script to continue executing before redirecting (even though it doesn't look like there's any more code in this case!)

Comment: @rjdown I usually do this: `die(header('Location:...'));` :)

Comment: the type is text in the database .

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check if there were any errors? any information is better than no information.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO messages VALUES('','".$name."', '".$message."')";
if($sqlrun = mysqli_query($connection , $sql)){
    header('Location:../write.php');
    exit();
}else{
    echo "query doesnt work: " . mysqli_error(); // jaaaj information!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why , but after i cheked the sql query time after time i realized that for the first argument in the values ( the '' which is dedicated for an auto-increment field) , i have to put NULL in there so that the query should be like this :

$sql = "INSERT INTO messages VALUES(NULL,'".$name."', '".$message."')";

again , i don't know exactly why now it works .

anyway thanks everyone !